# 404 redirection and Google's index

Tags: redirect, 404-error

I have several dead pages, which are annoyingly still indexed in Google.

I've set my 404.php to redirect to my homepage using wp_redirect, however I'm worried that this will prevent Google from unindexing those dead pages?

I've tried setting the status code in the redirect to 404, but this results in no redirection.